# Page cannot be charged because of mongodb errors Symfony 2

Tags: mongodb, symfony

After i made a clear cache i refreshed my page, but this time the browser looks like he doesn't find nothing or he is somewhere blocked, because it shows up near the address that he is searching or loading a page but it stays like that for long long time even hours i can tell.I checked error log and i found this error but i'm newbie i didn't understadn how to solve them:

```
  [Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP Fatal error:  Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Hydrator\\HydratorFactory::getHydratorFor(): Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/doctrine/odm/mongodb/Hydrators\\dcBundleDocumentCategoryHydrator.php' (include_path='.;C:\\php\\pear') in C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\vendor\\doctrine\\mongodb-odm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Hydrator\\HydratorFactory.php on line 152, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/gps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/gps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\web\\app_dev.php:0, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/gps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP   2. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->handle() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\web\\app_dev.php:25, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/gps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP   3. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:411, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/gps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP   4. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handle() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:1101, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/gps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP   5. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handleRaw() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:975, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/gps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP   6. call_user_func_array() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:1001, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/gps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP   7. bul\\CrsBundle\\Controller\\CrssController->AllAction() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:1001, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/gps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP   8. Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\Controller->render() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\src\\bul\\CrsBundle\\Controller\\CrsController.php:38, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP   9. Symfony\\Bundle\\TwigBundle\\TwigEngine->renderResponse() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\Controller.php:106, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  10. Symfony\\Bundle\\TwigBundle\\Debug\\TimedTwigEngine->render() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\TwigBundle\\TwigEngine.php:108, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/groups/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  11. Symfony\\Bundle\\TwigBundle\\TwigEngine->render() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\TwigBundle\\Debug\\TimedTwigEngine.php:52, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  12. Symfony\\Bridge\\Twig\\TwigEngine->render() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\TwigBundle\\TwigEngine.php:79, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  13. Twig_Template->render() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bridge\\Twig\\TwigEngine.php:53, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  14. Twig_Template->display() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\cache\\dev\\classes.php:6039, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  15. Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\cache\\dev\\classes.php:6032, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  16. __TwigTemplate_a9e184d390123fbf02da00b3fedfe39c->doDisplay() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\cache\\dev\\classes.php:6051, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  17. Twig_Template->display() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\cache\\dev\\twig\\a9\\e1\\84d390123fbf02da00b3fedfe39c.php:25, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  18. Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\cache\\dev\\classes.php:6032, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  19. __TwigTemplate_d7c51e8360cebc4fc46062c39aca8151->doDisplay() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\cache\\dev\\classes.php:6051, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  20. Twig_Template->displayBlock() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\cache\\dev\\twig\\d7\\c5\\1e8360cebc4fc46062c39aca8151.php:120, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  21. call_user_func() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\cache\\dev\\classes.php:5999, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  22. __TwigTemplate_a9e184d390123fbf02da00b3fedfe39c->block_body() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\cache\\dev\\classes.php:5999, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  23. Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Cursor->current() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\app\\cache\\dev\\classes.php:60, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  24. Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\UnitOfWork->getOrCreateDocument() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\vendor\\doctrine\\mongodb-odm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Cursor.php:118, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  25. Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Hydrator\\HydratorFactory->hydrate() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\vendor\\doctrine\\mongodb-odm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\UnitOfWork.php:2540, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
[Wed Aug 07 12:08:34.948850 2013] [:error] [pid 7800:tid 1016] [client ::1:56347] PHP  26. Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Hydrator\\HydratorFactory->getHydratorFor() C:\\wamp\\www\\Symfony\\vendor\\doctrine\\mongodb-odm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Hydrator\\HydratorFactory.php:419, referer: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/grps/
```

Comment: You didn't show the error message fully, making it impossible to help.

Comment: ok i will do it now, bc i thought the others eorro not so important

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved:I remove the Cache manually and I restart my pc again.It works now

Answer (score 0):

Your error says:

> Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/doctrine/odm/mongodb/Hydrators\dcBundleDocumentCategoryHydrator.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

Do you have that file?

Comment: No I didn't find it, but actually it's in cache , I mean it should be again generated. Or how can I solve this?

Comment: I solve it, i delete manually the cache and i restart my pc.Rpoblem soled ;)